# function within a function returning an object not working

Tags: php, database, function, pdo

I have some code which works:

```
$user = 'xxx';
$pass = 'xxx';
$db='vive';
$host ='localhost';
$name = 'chris';

function test($user, $pass, $db, $host){
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
else{
    echo 'Checkpoint 1.0 <br>';
        return $mysqli;
}
}
$mysqli2 = test($user, $pass, $db, $host);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `vive_user` WHERE `username` LIKE"."'$name'";
$result = $mysqli2->query($sql);
$num_results = $result->num_rows;
if ($result->num_rows>0)  ...
```

I am able to connect to the database and pull the information that I want out of the database everytime. I wanted to clean up my code a little (all the details are not shown), so i made a new function register() out of the last part of the code. In this new function, i want to call on function test() to return me a database connection object which I can then use to perform queries:

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$db='vive';
$host ='localhost';
$name = 'chris';

function test($user, $pass, $db, $host){
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
    else{
        echo 'Checkpoint 1.0 <br>';
            return $mysqli;
    }
}

function register($name){
    echo'test';

    global $user;
    global $pass;
    global $db;
    global $host;

    $mysqli2 = test($user, $pass, $db, $host);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `vive_user` WHERE `username` LIKE"."'$name'";
    $result = $mysqli2->query($sql);
    $num_results = $result->num_rows;
    if ($result->num_rows>0)...
}
```

For some reason the function register() will never give me any values from the database. I am unable to get anything for $result. Any help is appreciated, I have been dancing around the problem for a few days now. Note that in my actual code I have these two functions in different php files.

Comment: Does 'Checkpoint 1.0 <br>' get printed out when you run this?

Comment: In the future please be sure to x-out your login information before posting. Even though your db is on localhost it's very possible you have external connections to it enabled, and you should treat your IP address as public information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *LIKE* statement there in the query is missing *`%...%`* wrapper.

change the *register* to :

```
function register($name){

  global $user;
 global $pass;
 global $db;
 global $host;


  $name = "%".$name."%"; // see here..
    echo'test';
    $mysqli2 = test($user, $pass, $db, $host);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `vive_user` WHERE `username` LIKE"."'$name'";
    $result = $mysqli2->query($sql);
    $num_results = $result->num_rows;
    if ($result->num_rows>0)...
}
```

and make sure the method is called

Comment: @ratrace123, *no comment* at all? well..the world is getting silent, lol :D

Comment: im commenting (im at work and checking this periodically..). thanks for the help. so I made the global variable $name. so i also need to pass $user, $pass, $db and $host to the function register() for it to be used in the inner function test()?

Comment: and why does $name need to be global? If i define it at the beginning of the script and then pass it into the function register(), shouldnt it just be passed into the function test()? Arent i doing the same thing with $user, $pass, $db and $host? I am defining them at the beginning and then passing them into the function and not defining them as global? thanks

Comment: ok maybe i am really missing something here, but I thought that register() was the outer function and test() was the inner function, since test() is being called inside of register().

Comment: Oh yeah you're right LOL, somehow I missed to calculate the `{`, they're both separated functions, sorry it was 4.00 AM I've just woke up, and the title of your question is a bit misleading, so my conclusion would be you're just missing `%....%`

Comment: ok, so when I just wrap $name, it still does not work. It only works if i pass $user, $pass, $db and $host into the function register(). I guess that even if i define them at the beginning, they are still invisible in the function test() and need to be passed into the function test(), since it is inside another function register()..

Comment: i dont really understand rollback sry, new to the site. I think i am looking at your latest answer,  where I can click that you have edited your answer, and that appears to have redlines and new green txt which describe what i was saying to you about passing in $user, $pass, $db and $host to register()

Comment: @ratrace123, please try my latest update (I have just updated my answer), just try my latest answer, I've updated it,

Answer (score 0):

Why the where username like?

shouldn't it be where username = ?

also the quotes you used are redundant.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `vive_user` WHERE `username` LIKE"."'$name'";

could just be

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `vive_user` WHERE `username` = '$name'";

Comment: i read somewhere that using the LIKE allows for some margin/breathing room when looking up values so it does not need to be exact, maybe i should switch to "=". The quotes seem to be working, the main issue is what i described above.